# Symfony 2.6 automaticlly moving back date for one day

Tags: php, symfony, timezone

The problem occur after I switched SF from 2.5.7 to 2.6.2

I have a record in database contains a date field created based on entity variable

`/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", name="recieved_date", nullable=false)
*/
    protected $recievedDate;`

The value of the record in db is 2014-12-04, however after I load into form its move back automaticlly to 2014-12-03.

When I dumped the variable before create form `$this->createForm()` I have a correct

`object(DateTime)[1351]
  public 'date' => string '2014-12-04 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Warsaw' (length=13)`

With SF 2.5.7 everything was correct - do I need to set some specific timezone settings in SF 2.6?

Comment: It probably saves the date in UTC. So, when you have 2014-12-04 00:00:00 in Poland, it's still 2014-12-03 23:00:00 in UTC.

Comment: Any idea how to set it correctly then? Using date field on database you can not choose with or without timezone - I can not understand why Symfony2 change it by itself

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in symfony 2.6: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12808

[fix](https://github.com/Soullivaneuh/symfony/commit/ae5e9026273df1863a95b56a881a8370dd5846b2)